# How to make a result like this?

Tags: php, for-loop

How to make a result looks like this using for? please help. i dont know how to do this.

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

all i know is to make a result like this:

```
for($i=1; $i>=5; $i++){
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: You could use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/str_repeat).

Comment: try `$i<=5` for this loop

Comment: Try nesting one loop inside another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$size=5;
for($i=$size; $i>0; $i--){
    echo str_repeat("*", $i)."<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Because of flexibility, I store the size of the struct in an variable `$size`.
See also, [str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain it with a **countdown loop** and [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
for($i=5; $i>=1; $i--){
    echo str_repeat("*", $i) ."<br>";
}
```